# Как обработать нажатие на чекбокс

Tags: html, javascript

проблема следующая - необходимо по нажатию на чекбокс включать и выключать рефреш на странице. пытался js reload - шлак какой то выскакивает сообщение об повторной отправке данных (меняю данные в графике), ни о чем в общем.

```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

то что нужно, просто скидывает на дефолт, но как мне его включать.выключать в хеде?

Comment: @anunak, теги и заголовок вопроса мало соответствуют содержимому, советую Вам их изменить

Манипуляция мета тегами через dom насколько я знаю работать не будет. Так что вместо тега рефреш лучше обработать джаваскриптом

Comment: а как? reload мне пишет - отправить данные? ну вылазит это мерзкое окошко при каждом рефреше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал все на JS. Допустим, сначала автообновление выключено, галочка пустая.

По нажатию на нее ставится галочка и запускается `setTimeout()`, который через 30 секунд вызовет функцию, которая проверит, стоит ли все еще галочка, и если стоит, то направит браузер на URL этой страницы с доп. параметром: `page.php?refresh=1`.

Сервер же, заметив этот параметр, в выдаче включит галку, и допишет JS таким образом, что сразу при загрузке включится тот 30-секундный таймер.

Comment: вылазит окошко - отправить данные повторно?

Comment: Как вы это делаете? [Этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/fvLq9/) у меня в Хроме редиректит без диалогов (Mac OS, Chrome 34.0)

    function goAway(){
        window.location = location.href + "?test=123";
    }
    var t = setTimeout( goAway, 2000);

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('meta[http-equiv=refresh]').remove();
    $('head').append( '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">' );
});
</script>
```

Но поддержу пользователя [@Volt](/users/17812/volt) - это плохой подход.
Попробуйте дергать window.location

Comment: @ICE, сам не пробовал, но читал что в хроме это работать не будет, надо проверить

Answer (score 1):

Я бы еще посоветовал использовать cookie или localstorage чтобы включать-выключать флаг и в зависимости от этого запускать / не запускать таймаут с рефрешем.

Вот сделал грубый набросок этой реализации http://pastebin.com/b3BFf6vE

Comment: А еще можно модифицировать код таким образом, чтобы снятие галочки срабатывало моментально без лишней перезагрузки страницы ( использовать clearTimeout ) http://pastebin.com/T60F9qA7

Comment: на самом деле сделал так - запускаю сессию. если нажата кнопка, записываю значение. если значение есть - то беру значение из сессии, иначе просто текущее. а рефреш так и остается, т.к. нужен для других данных